# Change "A" to "G" in string "AGAG"

Tags: python

I did a Reverse function in order to reverse the text but I need to change also A for G.

```
def reverse(text):
    # Our empty string for the reversed text
    reversed_text = ""

    # Note: Indices are starting with zero and the last number in ranges aren't included
    for i in range(len(text)):   
        reversed_text += text[len(text)-1-i]
    return reversed_text
text = 'AGAGAGAGAGA'
print reverse(text)
```

So if I print this it will give me **AGAGAGAGAGA** but instead, I need **GAGAGAGAGA**

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use [extended slice notation](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices) to reverse a string in python.

Answer (score 1):

Using string slice operations makes it pretty easy to reverse text

```
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative - > `''.join(reversed("HelloWorld"))`